# Connecting Android device sensors with NodeRED

Tags: node.js, node-red

I am new bee to NodeRED. I refer tutorial on NodeRED connecting devices such as raspberry PI. The partial documentation on NodeRED Website is available that states that how developers can reads sensors connected to GPIO pins on Raspberry PI.

Similar way, I would like to know  - how can I read sensors (e.g., proximity sensors, GPS, Accelerometer) on Android device with NodeRED? More specifically, I would like to play with Android device sensors with NodeRED? I have tried to google documentations related to it, but did not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write an Android app to expose the sensors in a way that can be ingested into Node-RED, I would suggest publishing the values to a MQTT broker.

Node-RED can then subscribe to the topics and process the sensor values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It makes sense to me.

Comment: could you give a sample example in node RED that has MQTT subscriber to receive sensor data?

Comment: 1. https://gambitcomm.blogspot.com/2018/02/scaling-your-node-red-dashboard-with.html 2. https://github.com/gambitcomminc/node-red-sparkplug 3. https://github.com/gambitcomminc/nodered-mqtt-latency

Answer (score 0):

1. write an android app, that will expose the android sensor.
2. either push the data from Android to MQTT server (best choice) or use a microservice like AWS lamda or Firebase .
3. if used pub-sub with MQTT call it on Node-red, or call Lamda function Api endpoint on node-red or call the firebase directly on Node-red,
4. choose wisely according to your requirements.